# Categorizing failing test cases in jestjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I came to know that it is good to maintain failing unit test case for known defect or uncompleted feature. Is there any way to categorizing failing unit test cases in `jest.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to [skip](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html#testskipname-fn) the tests:

```
test.skip('it is not snowing', () => {
  expect(inchesOfSnow()).toBe(0);
});
```

Comment: At the time of answering this is true. There is not way to do that at that time

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own Queston

Now newer versions of Jest there is a way to do it

https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testfailingname-fn-timeout

```js
test.failing(name, fn, timeout)
```

```js
it.failing(name, fn, timeout)
```

As per the Jest documentation, This is only available with the default jest-circus runner.